# No auto Increment when MySql Database converted to Postgres database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, auto-increment

In `Mysql`, `ID` is `Auto Increment` but when converted to `Postgres`  there is no `Auto Increment` .

**Mysql database**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `district_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `state_id` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

**After Converted to postgres database**

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    "id" bigint NOT NULL,
    state_id bigint NOT NULL,
    district_id bigint NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(1000),
    created_by int NOT NULL,
    modified_by int,
    is_active char(1) NOT NULL,
    created timestamp,
    modified timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

INSERT INTO cities(state_id, district_id, city_type, name, description,  
     created_by, modified_by, is_active, created, modified) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, '', 'Ramtek', null, 1, null, 'Y',
     '2015-04-16 10:44:11', '2015-04-16 10:44:11');
```

Comment: change `"id" bigint NOT NULL,` to `id bigserial NOT NULL`. More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: And also refer http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `bigserial` in such cases. It provides an auto increment feature in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
   "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
```

Not Null constraint is provided by default.

Docs : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Thanks It worked, but one doubt when to use smallserial,bigserial and serial

Comment: From the docs "The type names serial and serial4 are equivalent: both create integer columns. The type names bigserial and serial8 work the same way, except that they create a bigint column. bigserial should be used if you anticipate the use of more than 231 identifiers over the lifetime of the table. The type names smallserial and serial2 also work the same way, except that they create a smallint column."

Comment: Now when I tried to add data from front end Its giving some database error SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column  violates not-null constraint, when I change my code to "id" bigserial NOT NULL,

Comment: Can  you post the query that you are inserting.

Comment: Can you post the complete log also ? And also the updated ddl of cities